# jQuery .attr() does not set in HTML after to set value and remove this attribute before

Tags: jquery, html, dom, attr

In my script, I need all the time on form items set attributes in HTML to save previous data and evaluate the next data before doing an ajax request.

Concerning `data-next-*` attributes, there are removed all the time after the script is done like this :

```
function actualizeTmpDataAndSpinner (){
       //Notice : "Value" is position value
       var a_dataValueKeys = [ "value", "is-condition", "condition-type", "condition-selector" ];

       for( var k=0 ; k < a_dataValueKeys.length; k++ ){
           $("*[data-previous-" + a_dataValueKeys[k] + "]").removeAttr( "data-previous-" + a_dataValueKeys[k] );
           $("*[data-next-" + a_dataValueKeys[k] + "]").each( function () {
           var dataNextValue = $(this).attr("data-next-" + a_dataValueKeys[k] );
           $(this).attr("data-" + a_dataValueKeys[k], dataNextValue );
       });
       $("*[data-next-" + a_dataValueKeys[k] + "]").removeAttr("data-next-" + a_dataValueKeys[k] );
   }
   $(".h4a-spinner-wrapper").remove();
}
```

For some reasons, after `data-next-*` was setup with values and removed, at a moment this following code line set attributes only in the DOM, and not in the HTML anymore :

```
function resetConditionForNext( $currentfieldConditionWrapper ) {
    $currentfieldConditionWrapper.attr('data-next-is-condition', "false" );
    $currentfieldConditionWrapper.attr('data-next-condition-type', "" );
    $currentfieldConditionWrapper.attr('data-next-condition-selector', "" );
}
```

**Output**

*In console*
[image]

*HTML Inspector*
[image]

Why `data-next-is-condition`, `data-next-condition-type` and `data-next-condition-selector` are not visible in the HTML inspector ?

Someone has got an explanation ?

Comment: Note: In JavaScript try to avoid using `$` in variable names. It's allowed, but it's also highly non-standard. JavaScript is not PHP or Perl.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the DOM and not the HTML"?

Comment: if I write `console.dir( $currentfieldConditionWrapper )`, I can see attributes but not in the HTML code Inspector.

Comment: The HTML never changes. That's rendered out by the server and sent to the browser once and once only. The DOM is the current state of the document and will change.

Comment: So the DOM won´t update the HTML ?

Comment: If by "HTML" you mean "View Source" then no, never. The HTML is loaded and immediately converted into what's represented as the DOM, but changes after that are not reflected in the source. If you want to rip the current state of the page *as* HTML you can do that using `innerHTML` on the `<html>` element.

Comment: What means the HTML never changes ? If I add an attribute on a HTML tag, the HTML changes...

Comment: Where are you adding an attribute? By editing the HTML source file? If so, sure, you can change it there, but you must reload the page for that change to take effect. What I mean is for any given page, the HTML source does not change unless you click a link, loading another page, or reload the page.

Comment: I´m using a classical jquery script  with `$(document).ready( function() {...` to modify the DOM and all the time, that appears in the "View Source" except in this case, when I can see it only with `console.dir()`

Comment: The JavaScript will show up in the source, sure. I think you're confusing what the HTML "View Source" view does with what the DOM is. The source is specifically, and only *what the browser loaded to render the page*, not what the browser is currently showing.

Comment: I modified my question with two screenshots to be clearer. About DOM and HTML Vocabulary. I´m based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr#answer-5875043)

Comment: Those are two different views of the same thing, both the DOM.

Comment: That is how it works. And you really should be using data() for data attributes.

Comment: @tadman, Yes and all the time these two views are the same, if I change attributes, you can see it in console view and HTML view. Why for this case it´s different  ?

Comment: @epascarello, all the time, it does not work like this because in this case, they are different. Each time I do a change with `.attr()` I should see the same result in both.
what do you mean by `data()`, I´m using the prefix  `data-` to make a difference with common attributes, it´s not correct ?

Comment: The title of this question makes absolutely no sense

Comment: `data-` implies [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) which jquery updates with [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what happened...

As the script removes `data-next-*` at the end, in order to check new attributes, I tried to use `alert("stop");` like this :

```
if( !$conditionCheckbox.is(":checked") ){
    resetConditionForNext( $currentConditionWrapper );
    console.dir( $currentConditionWrapper );
    alert("stop");
    break;
}
```

But `alert("stop");` is run before doing the change in HTML Inspector.

If I write an unknown javascript word like `exit;` instead of `alert("stop");` like this :

```
if( !$conditionCheckbox.is(":checked") ){
    resetConditionForNext( $currentConditionWrapper );
    console.dir( $currentConditionWrapper );
    exit;
    break;
}
```

The script is locked and the HTML Inspector is updated :

[image]